# How to implement the following markup with sticky header and footer using flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, markup

I'm learning CSS flexbox at the moment and I want to implement this markup:

[image]

1. I want the `header` and `footer` to be "sticky" (`header` is always on top and `footer` is always in the bottom).
2. If `article` or `aside1` or `aside2` size doesn't fit the page I want the area between header and footer to be scrollable.

So my plan was:

1. Create the container element with `display: flex` and `column direction` for it's items
2. It will contain 3 items: `header`, `footer` and the { `aside1`, `article` and `aside2` } which will be wrapped into another container.
3. This another container will have the `display: flex` itself with `row direction` for it's items: `aside`, `article` and `aside2`

My markup is very straightforward:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>This is header</header>
  
  <div class="content">
    <aside>aside1</aside>
    <article>article</article>
    <aside>aside2</aside>
  </div>

  <footer>This is footer</footer>
</div>
```

And here are the styles:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

/* Main wrapper, sizes = 100% to fit the viewport */
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  border: solid 1px black;
  flex-direction: column;
}

/* Just some styling, ignore this */
header,
article,
aside,
footer {
  border: solid 1px #888;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}

header {
  background-color: #cfffff;
}

/* flex: 1 makes it "stretch" allowing header and footer
to have their default sizes  */
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

aside {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: #cfffcf;
  width: 250px;
}

article {
  background-color: #ffcfff;
  flex: 1;
}

footer {
  background-color: #ffffcf;
}
```

The problem is that whenever `article` content overflows the container, the scrolling is not the way I expect it to be:

[image]

I want to understand:

1. Why this is happening?
2. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the new Style

```
position: sticky;
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100vh;
}

/* Main wrapper, sizes = 100% to fit the viewport */
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  border: solid 1px black;
  flex-direction: column;
}

/* Just some styling, ignore this */
header,
article,
aside,
footer {
  border: solid 1px #888;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}

header {
  background-color: #cfffff;
  position: sticky;
  top:0;
}

/* flex: 1 makes it "stretch" allowing header and footer
to have their default sizes  */
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

aside {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: #cfffcf;
  width: 250px;
}

article {
  background-color: #ffcfff;
  flex: 1;
}

footer {
position: sticky;
bottom:0;
  background-color: #ffffcf;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>This is header</header>
  
  <div class="content">
    <aside>aside1</aside>
    <article>article</article>
    <aside>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</aside>
  </div>

  <footer>This is footer</footer>
</div>
```